# mongodb C#: query the value of untyped nested document

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, querying

Here is an example of a BsonDocument in my database

```
{
    "employee": "A",
    "job history": [{
            "job name": "sales",
            "time": 2016
        },
        {
            "job name": "manager",
            "time": 2018,
            "location": [
                "NY",
                "OH"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I need a simple query like "name of the employee", I would go like this

```
var query = collection.Find(new BsonDocument("employee", "{}")).ToList();
```

Now, if I want to retrieve the value of "location", what should I do?

Comment: employee.location? Or are you asking how to search for just the location array?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to mongoDB but I can't find a detailed docs for it. I tried on their website but no hope, so I post my question here

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to get you going:

```
// search by employee field
var result = collection.Find("{ 'employee': 'A' }").ToList();
Console.WriteLine(result.First()["job history"].AsBsonArray[1].AsBsonDocument["location"]); // prints [NY, OH]

// search by location
result = collection.Find("{ 'job history.location': 'NY' }").ToList();
Console.WriteLine(result.First()["employee"]); // prints A
```